# Big O notation? Would that be O(n)?

Tags: data-structures

**What would be the Big O and Big Omega notation?**

```
int temp = 0
for (i =0; i < 100000000; i++)
         for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
                   temp = 0
                   while(temp < j)
                   {
                           temp++;
                   }
```

Comment: This code won't even compile in any language of which I'm aware.  Did you copy this from a whiteboard, and if so, could it be missing a few things?

Comment: Just consider that second loop is inside first and third loop is inside second.

Comment: Please edit your question to at least make it valid pseudo code; don't leave us guessing.

Comment: For the 1st loop, it is O(1), for second it is O(n). What it would be for 3rd loop? Would that be O(1) or O(n)? Thats what is confusing for me.

Comment: Sir is that ok now?

Comment: Over all the times the third loop runs it'll average 0.5 x n iterations. Since the 0.5 is a constant factor you can remove it and you'll end up with O(n) time complexity for the 3rd loop. The idea is that the first time it iterates 0 times, the last time n times so (0 + n) / 2 = 0.5n times on average. Then the second will iterate 1 time and the second to last will iterate n - 1 times giving (1 + (n - 1)) / 2 = 0.5n times...this continues giving the average 0.5n iterations

Comment: It is necessary to know what N is.

Comment: Is your code well written? Three loops? @MuhammadAhmadTariq
Edit well your code, or I'll have to flag the question.

Answer (score 1):

That thing is O(n^2), the innermost while runs from 0 to `j`, who's upper bound is `N`.

Comment: The question also asks about big Omega

Comment: I was correcting and more explained than yours. @blindy

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm's run time complexity is `O(n^2)`.

the outer loop repeats *constant* number of times (even if the constant is large, it is still a constant. 10^5 is no different than  10^100 in this regard).

The complexity is determined by the two inner loops. The innermost loop repeats j times and j goes from 0 to N.

`0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... +N = N(N+1)/2 => complexity function f(n) = 10^9 * N(N+1)/2 => O((f(n)) = N^2.`

This is also `Omega(N^2)` which means this algorithm is ultimately `Theta(N^2)`.

Remember that the big O and big Omega notation are about asymptotic limits meaning you will only need to find some random values after which f(n) <= c1g(n) (for upper bound) and f(n) >= c2h(n) (for lower bound). It should be easy to find such values for g(n)=h(n)= n^2.

In the end, you can squeeze f(n) (as defined above) between two c*n^2 functions with different multipliers.

Answer (score -1):

The Big Omega is used for the whole algorithm.

1. First loop will be executed `100000000 times` which is constant value.
2. Second loop would be executed `N times`.
3. The third loop is executed `N times at most`. (0, 1, 2, 3, ..., N)

The Big omega would be `O(100000000) * O(N) * O(N) = (100000000*N*((N+1)/2)) = O(N^2)`

The algorithm would have quadratic time complexity.

Comment: Why do you say the 3rd loop is never executed? If j==1000, doesn't it run 1000 times before temp reaches j?

Answer (score -2):

The overall time complexity of this algorithm will be O(n^3), assuming that the value 100 Million in the outermost loop is actually N.

Outermost loop will iterate n times. For every iteration, the first inner loop iterates n times. For every iteration of this inner loop, the second inner loop iterates n times in worst case, n/2 times on an average. So, the order of time complexity is in the order of n x n x n = n^3.

Comment: *"assuming that the value 100 Million in the outermost loop is actually N."* But it is not; it is 100 million.

Comment: I totally understand. My assumption was based on the original poster's poor quality of pseudo code, which does not even compile and he/she is super lazy to edit that also after pointed out by multiple users. I thought he/she actually meant N instead of 100M while copy pasting from somewhere

Comment: By definition, pseudocode is not expected to compile.